# Nancy.Testing exception thrown when testing POST route with Json content

Tags: nancy

I'm attempting to write tests for my Nancy module, and it's not going too well so far.

Attempting to test two separate actions, one `GET` which is working just fine and a `POST` with `application/json` content in the request.

I'm slightly stabbing in the dark as to how the test for the POST should be written, but have come up with the following:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class MyModuleTests
{
    Browser browser;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        browser = new Browser(with =>
        {
            with.Module<MyModule>();
            with.EnableAutoRegistration();
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Get_View()
    {
        // When
        var result = browser.Get("/View", with => with.HttpRequest());

        // Then
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode); // this works
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Post_to_EvaluateDocument()
    {
        var testData = new List<FakeInputValue>(){new FakeInputValue()
        {
            Name = "a",
            Value = 0.35
        }};

        // When
        var result = browser.Post("/Evaluate", with => //the exception is thrown on this line
        {
            with.HttpRequest();

            with.JsonBody<IList<FakeInputValue>>(testData);
        });

        // Then
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }
}

class FakeInputValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately this throws the following juicy error

```
1) Test Error : MyModuleTests.Can_Post_to_EvaluateDocument
System.Exception : ConfigurableBootstrapper Exception
----> Nancy.RequestExecutionException : Oh noes!
----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
----> System.MissingMethodException : No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
at Nancy.Testing.PassThroughStatusCodeHandler.Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
at Nancy.NancyEngine.CheckStatusCodeHandler(NancyContext context)
at Nancy.NancyEngine.<>c__DisplayClass8.<HandleRequestInternal>b__6(Task`1 completeTask)
at Nancy.NancyEngine.HandleRequestInternal(Request request, Func`2 preRequest)
at Nancy.NancyEngine.HandleRequest(Request request, Func`2 preRequest)
at Nancy.Testing.Browser.HandleRequest(String method, String path, Action`1 browserContext)
at MyModuleTests.Can_Post_to_EvaluateDocument() in line 49
--RequestExecutionException
at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
--TargetInvocationException
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Nancy.ModelBinding.DefaultBodyDeserializers.JsonBodyDeserializer.Deserialize(String contentType, Stream bodyStream, BindingContext context)
at Nancy.ModelBinding.DefaultBinder.Bind(NancyContext context, Type modelType, Object instance, BindingConfig configuration, String[] blackList)
at Nancy.ModelBinding.DynamicModelBinderAdapter.TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, Object& result)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
at MyModule.<.ctor>b__9(Object parameters)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object )
at Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
--MissingMethodException
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at Nancy.Json.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToObject(IDictionary`2 dict, Type type)
at Nancy.Json.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToList(ArrayList col, Type type)
at Nancy.Json.JavaScriptSerializer.ConvertToType[T](Object obj)
```

Any help as to (a) how I might better test `POST` routes with `application/json` content in Nancy or (b) resolve this particular error!

**edit 1**

My module is as follows:

```
public class MyModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyModule()
    {
        Get["/View"] = parameters =>
        {
            return View["myView"];
        };

        Post["/Evaluate"] = parameters =>
        {
            this.inputs = this.Bind<List<InputValue>>();
            var evaluator = new Evaluator(inputs);
            return Response.AsJson<List<Evaluation>>(evaluator.Evaluate()); 
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Needs more codez - Whats your Module look like? `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.` <-- this suggests you haven't setup your dependencies for testing.

Comment: I've added my code - there aren't any dependencies for the module.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of debugging and frustrated outputting to Console, I've tracked down the cause of the bug.  The issue was with the lack of public setters in my `InputValue` class.

The buggy class was written as so:

```
public class InputValue
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly double _value;

    public InputValue(string inputName, double inputValue)
    {
        this._name = inputName;
        this._value = inputValue;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._name;
        }
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._value;
        }
    }
}
```

I resolved the issue quite simply by allowing the properties to be set, as so:

```
public class InputValue
{
     public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```